Is there a possibility dataset is just not suitable for building accurate model?
I am trying to build a model for diabetes prediction by usage of Diabetes Health Indicators Dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexteboul/diabetes-health-indicators-dataset). I use Azure Machine Learning Studio (classic) where I tried both "Train Model" and "Tune Model Hyperparameters" (Random sweep) approach, but I cannot reach accuracy and/or other metrics above cca 72%. Dataset is balanced (35346 instances for 0 and 35346 instances for 1) and most of its features are just 0 or 1. I removed some of them they are not important for diabetes prediction (CholCheck, AnyHealthCare, NoDocbcCost, Education, Income).
https://i.ibb.co/Wn5cSY9/Bez-naslova.png
Is this dataset suitable for accurate prediction or I have to change approach to problem?

Yes, the dataset sometimes doesn't suit the algorithm you use to build the model.
For eg. if You are using continuous data and implementing classification techniques then there is a very high possibility that the evaluation metrics might not suit well in any order.
For that, you need to plot some graphs and heat maps to understand what type of dataset you have.
Make sure to change your approach if single one doesn't work.
To answer your question further, please add more details like what was your approach
